# Suggest edits to Company pages on Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits, jobs

Recently, I found some typos on a Company Page at Careers 2.0. I didn't find a nice, direct way to suggest the company to fix it.

I wonder if there is a way to suggest an edit to the company page, so the employer can accept, reject, or edit the page by itself. If this feature doesn't exist, I think it would be a nice one to be implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this would be a good idea.

Even if the company has to approve the edits it will still open them up to potential abuse.

If you are really that bothered about the mistakes I'm sure you could find their own website and use the contact details on that.

On the other hand - is a company that doesn't proof-read their job postings one you want to work for?

Comment: Ok, thanks! Actually yes. It's a nice company from Brazil, and I'm sure this typo was a point outside the curve. In their website the error does not repeat itself.